# How to use Mono.Gendarme on CentOS7?

Tags: linux, mono, gendarme

I can't find way to begin using Gendarme on my CentOS7 virtual machine.

Gendarme [documentation](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/gendarme):

> Gendarme is part of mono-tools and is available on most recent Linux distributions

But commands below do nothing:

```
gendarme 
man gendarme
```

I tried to install via any package manager but I didn't find anything useful.

My question: 
How to install gendarme on linux or how to begin to use it?

Comment: I've just built it from source when I've needed it : https://github.com/mono/mono-tools/tree/master/gendarme

Comment: It's not quite actively maintained but you can download its ZIP package and run on Mono.

Comment: @LexLi , where did you get ZIP? Could you give me a link?

Comment: @SushiHangover, what os do you use?

Comment: @KostyaVyrodov Multiple...

Comment: @SushiHangover, did you try CentOS?

Comment: @KostyaVyrodov Just did on CentOS 6.8 and Mono 4.8, the gendarme console ran fine.

Comment: @SushiHangover, thank you!

Comment: @KostyaVyrodov don't you ever go to the Mono homepage? http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/gendarme/ Binaries only is the section.